# FireDac Array Update Performance

Tags: delphi, firedac

In trying to update 10000 records by using batch update method over remote mysql connection. my server has 200+ms latency and by using this method it would take forever to do this since its sending queries one by one! any workaround?

```
query.params.arraysize := 10000;
query.sql.text := 'update table set field=:f1 where id=:f2;'
for i := 0 to query.params.arraysize-1 do
begin
query.params[0].asstrings[i] := 'VERY LONG STRING > 10KB';
query.params[1].asintegers[i] := id;
end;

query.execute(10000);
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you mean by _batch update_. What do you mean by that?

Comment: AFAIK does MySQL allow Array DML only for INSERT, not for UPDATE.

Comment: 1. by batch update i mean update many records at same time with out having to send multiple query.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Performance_of_the_Array_DML_Command_(FireDAC) here they indicate it can be used for UPDATE command too

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, and it is not doing "Batch" update, it just simply queue the queries and execute them one by one and get the result, not really effective when you are not connecting to local db

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Define the parameterized query.
2. Configure query params for performance.

*e.g:*

```
FDQuery1.Params[0].DataType := ftString;
```

1. Set the array size.
2. Supply the parameters values.
3. Execute the query in a transaction.

   ```
   FDConnection.StartTransaction; 
   try  
     FDQuery1.Execute(FDQuery1.Params.ArraySize);   
     FDConnection.Commit;
   except   
     FDConnection.Rollback;   
     raise; 
   end;
   ```

Comment: by using AsString im already setting datatype to be string, and you are rolling back after a commit, which i dont know the outcome.

Comment: Is your `finally` block supposed to be an `except` one?  As written, you are comminting the transaction, then unconditionally trying to roll it back!?

Comment: @user3001414  it is just for optimization  and you can make it better if you specify the size of string parameters

Comment: @MartynA thank you ,  Committed transactions are never rolled back.